# Coded UI FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenControlException

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I have 2 machines that both run IE 11. I have a script where I click on a radio button and it works on one machine, however, the same script is not able to click on that button and throws the FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenControlException exception.

Has anyone encountered this before that could shed some light into this situation? What could be causing this difference in playback on different machines running the same code on the same browser?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

`Control.WaitForControlExists()` before performing click event.

```
if(control.WaitForControlExists())
{
  control.Click();
}
```

or put some wait before click event :

`Playback.Wait(1000);`

Comment: Thanks, I will try and let you know. Have you experienced instances where the script finds an element on one computer, but does not on a different computer?

Comment: @user3648426: Not yet but There might be two possibilities for this issue:
1. Machine taking more time to load the control.
2. Control is hidden.